# Is there a way to create multiple dataframes from single dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want pandas code to create multiple dataframes from single dataframe using pandas.

For example, my main dataframe:

```
  col1      col2      col3
   HR       john      3000
   HR       tedd      4000
Logistic    muller    5000
Logistic    Kathy     1000
```

I want to create two dataframes one with `HR` and another with `Logistics`.

HR:

```
col1    col2   col3
HR      john   3000
HR      tedd   4000
```

Logistic:

```
col1      col2    col3
Logistic  muller  5000
Logistic  Kathy   1000
```